# How to find CPU usage for SQL server 2005 database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, cpu-usage

How to find CPU usage for SQL server 2005 Server

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN Article on [Troubleshooting Performance Problems in SQL Server 2005](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966540.aspx#EHAA)

> The following query gives you a
>   high-level view of which currently
>   cached batches or procedures are using
>   the most CPU. The query aggregates the
>   CPU consumed by all statements with
>   the same plan__handle (meaning that
>   they are part of the same batch or
>   procedure). If a given plan_handle has
>   more than one statement, you may have
>   to drill in further to find the
>   specific query that is the largest
>   contributor to the overall CPU usage.

```
select top 50  
    sum(qs.total_worker_time) as total_cpu_time,  
    sum(qs.execution_count) as total_execution_count, 
    count(*) as  number_of_statements,  
    qs.plan_handle  
from  
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs 
group by qs.plan_handle 
order by sum(qs.total_worker_time) desc
```

Comment: How do I get the plan_handle i.e. the query for that handle ?

Answer (score 0):

A few ways come to mind

- TaskManager
- [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)
- `Get-Process sqlservr |select CPU`
- WMI
- Performance Counters via PerfMon

Comment: Task Manager ..good ..thaks Scott

Comment: Performance counters ? where are they located ?

Comment: Start->Run..
Type: Perfmon

Answer (score 0):

Use performance counters http://tipsstation.com/article/SQL-Server-Performance-Counters.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A few more:

- WMI
- Peformance Counters
- SNMP

Answer (score 0):

Using sys.dm_exec_query_stats this you can find cpu usages by different SQL Server objects.
Below is a script:

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(st.dbid) AS DatabaseName
    ,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(st.objectid,dbid) AS SchemaName
    ,cp.objtype AS ObjectType
    ,OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid,dbid) AS Objects
    ,MAX(cp.usecounts)AS Total_Execution_count
    ,SUM(qs.total_worker_time) AS Total_CPU_Time
    ,SUM(qs.total_worker_time) / (max(cp.usecounts) * 1.0) AS Avg_CPU_Time 
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp 
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs 
    ON cp.plan_handle = qs.plan_handle
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) st
WHERE DB_NAME(st.dbid) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY DB_NAME(st.dbid),OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(objectid,st.dbid),cp.objtype,OBJECT_NAME(objectid,st.dbid) 
ORDER BY sum(qs.total_worker_time) desc
```

In this result of the script, you can find type of objects and different calculation for CPU time.